# Rails carmen-rails gem, find subregion name by subregion code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carmen

am using carmen rails gem for to select country and subregion. after implemented database saving the country code and subregion code.
I can get the country name from code using this 
`@country_name = Carmen::Country.coded(country_code)`
Now i want to get subregion name from subregion code.  
Help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `coded` and `named` methods that you use with `Carmen::Country` can also be used with the subregions collection.

```
@country = Carmen::Country.coded(country_code)
@subregion = @country.subregions.coded(subregion_code)
```